# Querying google search engine from python script

Tags: javascript, python, r, matlab, google-search

I have more than one thousand rows in a csv file and I want to make a script (js,python, R or matlab) in order to query a search engine (e.g. google or any other) and apply regular expression in the output to append columns in the csv. I would like to ask you if google search engine has **restriction** in queries from scripts?

Also, do you know an **efficient way or any hint** to do this?

King regards,
Dimitris

Comment: I have used bing to do similar thing. Python with urlib.request and beautifulsoup worked. Just change thr query string.  Google detected that I was not a real user.

Comment: You could use [the Google API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest) and provide your data as the query parameter.

Comment: I doubt that it is thr RIGHT way to do this, but well it works

Comment: @Usmiech I am going to do exactly what you decribe but I am wondering about google restrictions. Does google prevent you script?

Comment: It works with bing. At least worked a year ago

Comment: @Usmiech thank you!

Comment: @Jonarz thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If You want to make Python Scripts, that can do a **Google Search** With **Query Parameters**?

you can try AutoPythonLauncher Automation Software [Click Here.](http://autopythonclipboardlauncher.com/)

Go Here [Create a Taskbar Launcher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxSA5t4CPXU) and Look to the end of this Youtube Tutorial.

With this Tool you can Make very fast On your Windows Desktop a set of **Clickable Button Icons** with **Python Scripts**. You can Simple Select any text from everywhere (any sort of Application) For example: Select text in any rows from your csv file and then do direct in One Mouse or Touch Click (Button icon) a **Google Search** With **Query Parameters** - The Computer Find Automatic Out Where it can do the Google Search (What browser it must Use)

Step 1 - Make a set of Button Icons.

Step 2 - Choose a Button icon and Make a Python Script in the Command Editor.

Step 3 - Save and Restart Buttoncommander and You are Ready to use it as a Launcher.

```
from pyreg import *
import pyautogui
import time
import Tkinter as tk

# US - SEARCH
# Firefox Mozilla Browser - Chrome Browser - Internet Explorer Browser - Microsoft Edge Browser 
if WindowExists("MozillaWindowClass") or WindowExists("Chrome_WidgetWin_1")  or WindowExists("CLASS:IEFrame"):
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c') #copy the selected text to clipboard 1 memory
    time.sleep(0.2)    #wait 0.2 seconds
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 't') # CTRL+t make a new tab + goto address bar  - use CTRL+L for the active tab + goto address bar
    time.sleep(0.2)    #wait 0.2 seconds
    texta = "https://www.google.com/search?q="
    a = tk.Tk()
    textb = a.clipboard_get() # read the clipboard memory and put in variable textb
    textc = "&lr=lang_us&hl=us&num=50" # google parameters [us - United States]
    pyautogui.typewrite(texta + textb + textc)
    pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
```

Note - in this part of Code Line you can Restrict a Query Search. (For example: only us with 50 results)

```
textc = "&lr=lang_us&hl=us&num=50" # google parameters
```

Tip - you can Make Python Scripts that can execute Computer Movements with Keyboard Shortcuts Macros. 
(For Example: Find a words and replace it into other word)